# Geth not syncing on testnet

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm trying to run geth on a new mac and it gets stuck when trying to sync.
I'm running `geth --testnet --syncmode "fast"`

This is the console output:

> INFO [01-06|11:33:20] Starting peer-to-peer node
>   instance=Geth/v1.7.3-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.9.2 INFO [01-06|11:33:20]
>   Allocated cache and file handles
>   database=/Users/pabloruiz55/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata
>   cache=128 handles=1024 INFO [01-06|11:33:20] Writing custom genesis
>   block  INFO [01-06|11:33:20] Initialised chain configuration
>   config="{ChainID: 3 Homestead: 0 DAO:  DAOSupport: true EIP150: 0
>   EIP155: 10 EIP158: 10 Byzantium: 1700000 Engine: ethash}" INFO
>   [01-06|11:33:20] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches
>   dir=/Users/pabloruiz55/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth/ethash count=3
>   INFO [01-06|11:33:20] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs
>   dir=/Users/pabloruiz55/.ethash                              count=2
>   INFO [01-06|11:33:20] Initialising Ethereum protocol
>   versions="[63 62]" network=3 INFO [01-06|11:33:20] Loaded most recent
>   local header          number=0 hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576 INFO
>   [01-06|11:33:20] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0
>   hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576 INFO [01-06|11:33:20] Loaded most recent
>   local fast block      number=0 hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576 INFO
>   [01-06|11:33:20] Regenerated local transaction journal
>   transactions=0 accounts=0 INFO [01-06|11:33:20] Starting P2P
>   networking  INFO [01-06|11:33:23] UDP listener up
>   self=enode://cff9f6def208edea618095eeec2b2f96532188e248775447c14bcf092eb73f97ed27411f56b1737d3caf0815b677c1b47cc72dbb8c0ab7ef4d2f0192c56a23e6@190.55.195.86:30303
>   INFO [01-06|11:33:23] RLPx listener up
>   self=enode://cff9f6def208edea618095eeec2b2f96532188e248775447c14bcf092eb73f97ed27411f56b1737d3caf0815b677c1b47cc72dbb8c0ab7ef4d2f0192c56a23e6@190.55.195.86:30303
>   INFO [01-06|11:33:23] IPC endpoint opened:
>   /Users/pabloruiz55/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc

It always gets stuck after that last message.
Tried using --syncmode "light" or just geth --testnet, but it's the same.

Syncing mainnet DOES work.
Syncing Rinkeby DOES work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What the output of `eth.syncing`? Also try to setup larger cache, you've setuped `cache=128`.

Comment: Few weeks ago I had similar issues in syncing. Then moved to Parity. Works like a charm.

Comment: eth.syncing = false and current block = 0, I'll try increasing the cache.

Comment: Since yesterday I've tried to sync with different internet connections and it always show _"dial tcp 52.169.14.227:30303: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."_ when launching geth with `--verbosity 6`

Comment: Haven't tried again. I ultimately gave up and went to sync on Rinkeby.

Comment: I am trying to sync via geth as well as parity but to no avail. In geth when I put --debug --verbosity 5, New dial task, Skipping dial candidate, Bumping findnode failure counter, Dial error                               task="dyndial 6ce05930c72abc63 13.84.180.240:30303" err="dial tcp 13.84.180.240:30303: getsockopt: connection refused"
occur repeatedly,

Comment: Ropsten also does not sync with parity

Answer (score 14):

I found this node: `enode://94c15d1b9e2fe7ce56e458b9a3b672ef11894ddedd0c6f247e0f1d3487f52b66208fb4aeb8179fce6e3a749ea93ed147c37976d67af557508d199d9594c35f09@192.81.208.223:30303` on this page:

> https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten/issues/13

and it seemed to fix my issue.

```
bash$ geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303,enode://94c15d1b9e2fe7ce56e458b9a3b672ef11894ddedd0c6f247e0f1d3487f52b66208fb4aeb8179fce6e3a749ea93ed147c37976d67af557508d199d9594c35f09@192.81.208.223:30303" --verbosity=6
```

Comment: Wow I have been fighting with this one, thanks for posting this, it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Try to run

```
geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --cache=1024 console
```

and then in console:

```
admin.addPeer('enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303')
admin.addPeer('enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303')
```

---

[Ropsten Troubleshooting](https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten#troubleshooting)

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't work. Same behavior.

Comment: Does not work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I have synced geth 1.8.15 to Ropsten, after adding some resources.  I am using an ec2 t3 medium; two cores, 4 g ram, and 150 g ssd.  Before bumping the processor, I was running out of memory on a t2 micro with a 30 g drive.  Bumping the host solved the memory problem, but the drive thrashed.  I'm hoping the 150 g drive will accommodate the live net.  I start geth with geth --testnet, plus arguments to start the rpc server.